# Docker error of overlay on DevOps used to work earlier

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, continuous-integration, production

#get python FROM openjdk:8 COPY --from=python:3.9 / /
##using working directory WORKDIR /

copy all content from current directory to app ADD . /

#installing python packages

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org -r requirements.txt RUN pip install --user traitlets COPY .databricks-connect /root/ EXPOSE 15005
#getting jdk CMD [“python”,“run.py”]

the above throws and error of
##[error ]ERROR: failed to solve: cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/gp102u40agddd@y4d9iqj4pv9/merged/bin with file
#Terror The process /usr/bin/docker’ failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to fix the Dockerfile formatting?  It looks like you might have an `ADD` directive that's targeting the image root directory; could you choose a different directory `WORKDIR /app` and then use that directory as the target `COPY ./ ./`?